# passing columnname with a parameter SQLcommand

Tags: c#, parameters, sqlcommand

I've been googling something I dont really cant understand.
In short my problem is this;

When using this;

```
String sYear2 = "2020";
string query = @"Select decJan from Stats where intRecnum = (select intRecnum from Stats where intAr = @year)";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", sYear2);
```

The result is returning "111" (which is correct vaule of column decJan the year 2020.

But when trying this;

```
String sYear2 = "2020";
String sColumn2 = "decJan";
string query = @"Select " + @column + @" from tbFuGraddagar where intRecnum = (select intRecnum from tbfuGraddagar where intAr = @year)";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", sYear2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", sColumn2);
```

I recieve "decJan" as result.

When googling all I have found that its not possible without dynamic SQL or that is bad design.

But I fail to understand what the diffrence is...all I want is to change the static code with a value similar to @year-parameter. the "interpretation" shouldn't care about the validation of SQL-syntax, it's just a matter och string-manipulation.

Or is it just me beeing a bad C#-coder?

Comment: It's bad design all right, and it's not possible to pass table or column names as parameters. The schema in a SQL query is equivalent to the type in a strongly-typed language. Queries aren't executed directly. They are compiled into execution plans that use multiple data access strategies, matching algorithms and caching, based on the *specific* table, column, indexes and data statistics. If a table is small enough, the server may load all of it in memory and use it for lookups. Or it may use different join strategies, eg loops vs hash joins

Comment: The table and column, the types and indexes are equivalent to types in a strongly-typed language. If you change them, you change the program completely. In this case, the program is the execution plan

Comment: I would use SQL Server Management Studio to test the query before trying in c#.  The SSMS error message are much better than c# and usually will resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably addwithvalue method is not valid for adding dynamic column names in select statements. I think you should use c# 8.0 feature, string interpolation to solve this problem.  You can add column names with string interpolation. Can you try this approach :

```
String sYear2 = "2020";

string deccan = "decJan";

string query = $(Select {decJan} from Stats where intRecnum = (select intRecnum from Stats where intAr = @year)


query = @query;


var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", sYear2);
```

Comment: dont know if this solution fits under "bad design" but its exactly what I was after. Manipulate a string before it is sent to execution.